# Drawing tileMap unto "background" - Not working after putting it into a class. No Error Messages

Tags: python

I'm not sure what the problem is because I am not getting any error messages - as if the class wasn't even being called..? I have a working version of this code that doesn't use any classes (I'm still learning Python syntax as I am coming from C++). I don't know what to do or really how to explain the issue besides "I won't draw".

```
#python3 -OO main.py
import pygame
import json
import csv
import sys
import os

#OS
xMax = 800
yMax = 640
xWin = 1366 - xMax #pins Window to top right of the display
yWin = 0
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "%d, %d" % (xWin, yWin)

#PYGAME
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("DEMO")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, yMax))
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 30)

with open('saves/save.json') as save_file:
    data = json.load(save_file)

class Background:
    tileSize = 16
    tile_images = {
        1: pygame.image.load("resources/graphics/sprites/grass.png"),
        2: pygame.image.load("resources/graphics/sprites/water.png"),
        3: pygame.image.load("resources/graphics/sprites/tree.png"),
        4: pygame.image.load("resources/graphics/sprites/bones.png"),
        5: pygame.image.load("resources/graphics/sprites/rocks.png"),
        6: pygame.image.load("resources/graphics/sprites/brick1.png"),
        7: pygame.image.load("resources/graphics/sprites/brick2.png"),
        8: pygame.image.load("resources/graphics/sprites/tree2.png")
    }
    
    tileMap = []
    with open("resouces/maps/demo.csv", "r") as file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
        for row in csv_reader:
            tileMap.append([int(tile_id) for tile_id in row])

    def __init__(self, tile_images, tileSize, tileMap):
        self.tile_images = tile_images
        self.tileSize = tileSize
        self.tileMap = tileMap

    def draw(self, screen):
        background = pygame.Surface((len(self.tileMap[0]) * self.tileSize, len(self.tileMap) * self.tileSize))
        for row in range(len(self.tileMap)):
            for col in range(len(self.tileMap[0])):
                tile_id = self.tileMap[row][col]
                if tile_id in self.tile_images:
                    tile_image = self.tile_images[tile_id]
                    background.blit(tile_image, (col * self.tileSize, row * self.tileSize))
        screen.blit(background, (0, 0))

class Player:
    def __init__(self, position, player_path):
        self.position = position
        self.image = pygame.image.load(player_path)
        self.speed = 16
        
    def move(self, keys):
        x, y = self.position
        speed = self.speed
        
        if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > 0:
            y -= speed
        elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            y += speed
        elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 0:
            x -= speed
        elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            x += speed
        self.position = (x, y)
   
    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, (self.position))
        
def update_data(player):
    data['player_x'] = player.position[0]
    data['player_y'] = player.position[1]
    with open('saves/save.json', 'w') as save_file:
        json.dump(data, save_file)
        
def main():
    background = Background(tile_images, tileSize, tileMap)
    player_path = "resources/graphics/sprites/player1.png"
    position = (data['player_x'], data['player_y'])
    player = Player(position, player_path)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while True:
        clock.tick(60)
        mbreak = False
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                mbreak = True
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            mbreak = True
        player.move(keys)
        screen.fill(0x0) #I've tried commenting this out because I thought it was drawing over the background
        
        background.draw(screen)
        player.draw(screen)

        text = f'{player.position[0]}, {player.position[1]}'
        img = font.render(text, True, (0xFFFFFFFF))
        screen.blit(img, (20, 20))
      
        pygame.display.update()
        if mbreak:
            break
        
    update_data(player)
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You'll probably want to remove the slew of code that has nothing to do with the problem. There's a ton of code here that's just not related to the problem you're talking about, and so just gets in the way when people try to read your post. Remember to give ["how to ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask) a read through (ideally _before_ posting, but too late now; thankfully the [edit] button is always there), and give the [mcve] article a read through as well if you're having trouble reducing your code.

Comment: LOL - there was a typo "resouces" instead of "resources".

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if that will solve the problem but putting some code just inside the class, not inside any function, is probably a bad idea as I have never seen it. The following code should be part of **init** or **main**:

```
tileSize = 16
tile_images = {
    1: pygame.image.load("resources/graphics/sprites/grass.png"),
    2: pygame.image.load("resources/graphics/sprites/water.png"),
    3: pygame.image.load("resources/graphics/sprites/tree.png"),
    4: pygame.image.load("resources/graphics/sprites/bones.png"),
    5: pygame.image.load("resources/graphics/sprites/rocks.png"),
    6: pygame.image.load("resources/graphics/sprites/brick1.png"),
    7: pygame.image.load("resources/graphics/sprites/brick2.png"),
    8: pygame.image.load("resources/graphics/sprites/tree2.png")
}

tileMap = []
with open("resouces/maps/demo.csv", "r") as file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in csv_reader:
        tileMap.append([int(tile_id) for tile_id in row])
```